# Java: Generating a tree from xml file

Tags: java

I am having trouble with writing a recursive function that retrieves information from an xml file and produces a tree structure. It is supposed to be done recursively. Please help me I have been stuck on this for a week putting in almost 6 hours a day. Thanks.

The problem is that I get this exception:
IllegalArgumentException: new child is an ancestor

and it is the recursive call that is causing it.

```
This is my code: 

   public class MyNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
    private String level;
    private String name;
    private String text;

    public MyNode(String level, String name, String text){
        super(name);
        this.level = level;
        this.text = text;
       }

    }

--------

    public MyLifeTree_2() {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        //*** Build the tree and a mouse listener to handle clicks

        try{
            sc = new Scanner(new File("src/Liv.xml"));
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        root = readNode(sc); // line 30

        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel( root );
        tree = new JTree( treeModel );
        MouseListener ml =
                new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
                        if ( box.isSelected() )
                            showDetails( tree.getPathForLocation( e.getX(),
                                    e.getY() ) );
                    }
                };
        tree.addMouseListener( ml );
        //*** build the tree by adding the nodes
        //*** panel the JFrame to hold controls and the tree
        controls = new JPanel();
        box = new JCheckBox( showString );
        init(); //** set colors, fonts, etc. and add buttons
        c.add( controls, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        c.add( tree, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        setVisible( true ); //** display the framed window
    }


    private MyNode readNode(Scanner sc){
        MyNode retNode = null;

        if(sc.hasNext()){
            sc.nextLine();
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            Scanner ls = new Scanner(line);
            String w = ls.next();
            String level = w.substring(1);
            System.out.println(level);
            w =  ls.next();
            String name = w.substring(6,w.length()-2);
            System.out.println(name);
            String text = ls.next();
            System.out.println(text);
            retNode = new MyNode(level, name, text);
            String sw = sc.nextLine();
            if(sw.startsWith("</")){
                sc.nextLine();
                return retNode;
            } else {
                readNode(sc);
                retNode.add(retNode); // line 98
            }
        }
        return retNode;
    }

-----

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <PremierLeague name="PremierLeague"> this is the PM
    <Div1 name="Div1"> is under PM
    <Teams name="team1"> has sth
    <Player name="name1"> plays attack
    </Player>
    <Player name="name2"> plays attack
    </Player>
    </Teams>
    </Div1>
    </PremierLeague> 

PremierLeague
PremierLeague
this
Player
name1
plays
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new child is an ancestor
        at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.insert(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:179)
        at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.add(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:411)
        at MyLifeTree_2.readNode(MyLifeTree_2.java:98)
        at MyLifeTree_2.<init>(MyLifeTree_2.java:30)
        at MyLifeTree_2.main(MyLifeTree_2.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly is not working?

Comment: @EJK The problem is that I get this exception: IllegalArgumentException: new child is an ancestor

Comment: It would help if you posted the full stack trace of your exception.  Be sure to indicate the line of your code that triggered the problem (this will not be obvious to anyone as the stack trace will have line numbers, but the code you posted does not).

Comment: @EJK I have updated my question

Comment: Can you please indicate in your code which line is: MyLifeTree_2.java:98?

Comment: Also please post your console output - i.e. the output from your System.out.println calls.

Comment: @EJK I have added the System.out.println calls and I have commented on the right of the code which line is 98

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're trying to add a Node as a child of itself, which isn't allowed. You need to do this instead:

```
} else {

    retNode.add(readNode(sc)); // line 98 <-- this will recursively add nodes beneath this one
    return retNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works but it doesn't go through the whole document.

Comment: @Lebowski, you'll need to debug it a bit to figure out where it's having problems. You also need to spend sometime thinking about how recursion works and how you want to process this document. For example, the `sc.nextLine()` call inside the `if` block is probably not what you want. Seems like homework, have you talked to your professor?

Comment: It is homework and I have but I didn't understand what he was saying. I will see him again tomorrow. I just feel so incompetent since there are many in my class that have done this. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Lebowski recursion is initially conceptually very strange! It takes a different way of thinking. Once it clicks for you, it'll come very easily. But until then, it's very difficult.